# What is the difference between `-Q` and `-q --no-init-file --nosplash`

Tags: start-up, x11

I have started seeing some strange X related behaviour in emacs. I have not been able to pin it down. It goes away when I run `emacs -Q`, but is still present when running `emacs -q --no-init-file --nosplash`.

The man page says:

> -Q, --quick
>      Similar to "-q --no-site-file --no-splash".  Also, avoid processing X resources.

What is the difference?

What does *avoid processing X resources* mean?

What does that tell me about my problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Q` also uses `--no-site-lisp`. See the Emacs manual, node [Initial Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html).

For information about X resources, see node [Resources](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Resources.html).

Learn to *ask Emacs*: `C-h r`, then `i` and type some text to match an index entry, then `TAB` to see the matches, and choose one.

You can find `i` and other manual-browsing keys by doing `C-h m` in the manual. `C-h m` in any mode gives you information about that mode.

Comment: So the man page is incorrect, but it warns about that:  `This man page is updated only when someone volunteers to do so`.

Comment: `C-h r` is a good one, thanks! also +1 on "Learn to ask Emacs" tip.